# Qt C++ writing data in a file , unexpected output

Tags: c++, qt

I have a task to save a file to computer. So this is my problem, when i write to file , it writes hex values.. I have no clue, what's wrong with my code. Here it is:

```
void MainWindow::on_actionSave_triggered()
{
    QString filename = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(
            this,
            tr("Save Document"),
            QDir::currentPath(),
            tr("Documents (*.txt)") );
    QFile f( filename );
    f.open( QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text );
    QTextStream out(&f);
    out << ui->textEdit->document();

}
```

Answer (score 5):

QTextEdit's document method return QTextDocument, I think you want to use toPlainText method instead.

Comment: out << ui->textEdit->document()->toPlainText();

Answer (score 1):

`QTextEdit::document()` will return a `QTextDocument*` which will be an Hex value *(address)*. That's what you are adding in the file.

To get the contents from the QTextEdit use [`QString QTextEdit::toPlainText ()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qtextedit.html#plainText-prop)

HTH..